# Insufficient Acces (50) LDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am trying to execute a custom .ldif file at the beggining of the startup of OpenLDAP server and have succeded using the following command:

```
ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=vlad,dc=lan -w admin -H ldap:// -f ldap/ldap-test.ldif
```

Sadly, I want to be able to add custom attributes and objectclasses into the schema using the following:

```
dn: cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcObjectClasses
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.0 NAME 'myCustomObjectClass'
  DESC 'My Custom Object Class'
  AUXILIARY
  MAY ( customAttribute1 $ customAttribute2 $ customAttribute3 $
        customAttribute4 $ customAttribute5 $ customAttribute6 $
        customAttribute7 $ customAttribute8 $ customAttribute9 $
        customAttribute10 $ customAttribute11 $ customAttribute12 $
        customAttribute13 $ customAttribute14 $ customAttribute15 ) )
```

Sadly, it throws the insufficient access 50 error. This is the output of slapcat -n0

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcDatabase: {0}config
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=extern
 al,cn=auth manage by * break
olcRootDN: cn=admin,cn=config
structuralObjectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
entryUUID: 3e49b716-55fd-103e-8582-a14a85261557
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20240202095739Z
olcRootPW:: e1NTSEF9d3J4NGVYaUFvaGRmc2dDOXlqT0V0cEFmSWhZYklxWXo=
entryCSN: 20240202095739.321947Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
modifyTimestamp: 20240202095739Z

dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}mdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcSuffix: dc=vlad,dc=lan
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=vlad,dc=lan
olcRootPW:: -----
olcDbCheckpoint: 512 30
olcDbMaxSize: 1073741824
structuralObjectClass: olcMdbConfig
entryUUID: 3e49fae6-55fd-103e-8589-a14a85261557
creatorsName: cn=admin,cn=config
createTimestamp: 20240202095739Z
olcDbIndex: uid eq
olcDbIndex: mail eq
olcDbIndex: memberOf eq
olcDbIndex: entryCSN eq
olcDbIndex: entryUUID eq
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=extern
 al,cn=auth manage by * break
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by dn="cn
 =admin,dc=vlad,dc=lan" write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {2}to * by self read by dn="cn=admin,dc=vlad,dc=lan" wri
 te by dn="cn=user-ro,dc=vlad,dc=lan" read by * none
entryCSN: 20240202095739.438344Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
modifyTimestamp: 20240202095739Z
```

How can I make it so that I can run the above command using ldapadd or ldapmodify? What user is needed to auth.

UPDATE:
`dn: cn=schema,cn=config changetype: modify add: olcObjectClasses olcObjectClasses: ( 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.0 NAME 'myCustomObjectClass' DESC 'My Custom Object Class' AUXILIARY MAY ( name ) )`

Used above code with command: ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:// -f ldap/ldap-modify.ldif

All seems fine, should be added.

Tried using the class:

```
dn: OU=CustomOU,DC=vlad,DC=lan
ou: CustomOU
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: myCustomObjectClass
```

With the command and it says:

```
ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=vlad,dc=lan -w admin -H ldap:// -f ldap/ldap-test.ldif 

additional info: objectClass: value #2 invalid per syntax
```

And when checking the slapcat -n0, it does not appear that the custom object was added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two separate databases (the "cn=config" database and your "normal" database) and you need to keep in mind that they have different access policies configured.

The DN `cn=admin,dc=vlad,dc=lan` is listed as the rootDN of your "normal" database **only** – it does not automatically get "root" privileges to other databases – and the `olcAccess` attributes are likewise set per-database, granting this DN some privileges (and redundantly so) only on the "normal" database whereas the "config" database has none of those access grants.

Because you're trying to modify an entry under `..., cn=config`, you must look at the configuration of "olcDatabase={0}config" first. It has a completely different olcRootDN for "superuser" access (the password may be identical, or it may be different), and its olcAccess attributes only grant full access to local, UID-identified connections – *not* to the DN that you're currently trying to bind (log in) as.

So you have two options:

- either bind as `cn=admin,cn=config` which is the rootDN of this database (assuming you know the password):

  ```
   ldapmodify -x -D cn=admin,cn=config ...
  ```
- or make a local connection identified by your Linux UID (which is then granted access via olcAccess). The access list specifies uidNumber=0 which is root, so you need to 'sudo' the whole thing.

  ```
   sudo ldapmodify -H ldapi:// -Y EXTERNAL ...
  ```

  Note that there is no `-x` or `-D` in this case; instead you use SASL bind with the `-Y` option. The URL `ldapi://` will connect through a local Unix socket, allowing UID-based authentication to work. (If it were a TCP connection, then EXTERNAL would mean mTLS client certificate auth which is not what you need here.)

  This is similar to how Postgres and recently also MariaDB work (e.g. on Debian, doing `sudo mariadb` will immediately connect as MariaDB root user).

Comment: Added an update.

Comment: The update describes a completely different problem than the original. Did the initial ldapmodify succeed? (I _think_ you cannot directly modify cn=schema in OpenLDAP – if I remember correctly that's only an "aggregate" view of all loaded schemas, while your custom additions need to be done on a child entry like `cn=foo,cn=schema,cn=config`.)

Comment: It did not succeed. It does not appear anywhere in slapcat -n0. @ui1686_grawity

Comment: Even when trying with dn: cn={0}core,cn=schema,cn=config, they do not appear to have been added.